# How to bundle external dependencies using gulp

Tags: gulp, browserify

I'm trying to bundle external commonjs modules (react, react-dom) together with some plain ES5 files, like pollyfills.js.

I can bundle the external modules using browserify.require

```
var externalBundler = browserify();
config.externalModules.forEach(externalBundler.bundle);
return externalBundler.bundle()
  .pipe(source("external.js"))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ debug: true, loadMaps: true }))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

and the other scripts using gulp.concat, however I struggle to put them toggether.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to combine the pipes like this:

```
gulp.task('bundle-externalscripts', function () {
  var externalBundler = browserify({ debug: true });
  for (var module of config.externalModules) externalBundler.require(module);

  var globalScripts = gulp.src(paths.scripts);

  var externalModules = externalBundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source("externalmodules.js")) //always convert to vinyl source stream
    .pipe(buffer());                //in buffered mode

  return merge(globalScripts, externalModules)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ debug: true, loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(concat("external.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```